# phone number regex with + or - characters

Tags: regex, cakephp

I wish to validate a group of phone number, and allow to up add + character or - character into the phone number, but optional, phone number total digits is not need to setup as 10 digits. 
in CakePHP. How might I do this?

example of valid input:

0165561125

016 5542512

+016 5515241

+016-5512412

Comment: Have you tried writing any sort of regex at all?

Comment: i just tried this on a regex generator, but that's was javascript code generator show me this    /\d|\+|-/
and i try to change as cake 
as this :
'phone' => array(
 'rule' => array('/d[\+\-]/'),

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex.

```
\+?\d{3}[- ]?\d{7}
```

`\+?` looks for a `+` and makes it optional.
`\d{3}` looks for three digits.
`[- ]?` looks for a `-` or a space, optional again. Note than ? makes the preceding character optional.
`\d{7}` looks for the remaining 7 digits.

As you mentioned, there can be any number of spaces or - in your phone number, you could use the following regex:

```
\+?(\d+[ -]?)+
```

Comment: but i don't want to set a digit range for the input .
in case i need a input as +65 553 4730 ?
so how could this work ?

Comment: See its always better to have some specified formats before making a regex. Large variations would allow great chances of violations.

Comment: well but how did i use to declare in model ?
this my ways , try to fix me if there got something wrong.
phone' => array(
  'notempty' => array(
   'rule' => array('custom','\+?(\d+[ -]?)+'),
),   ),

Comment: Well being honest, i don't have much idea about this language, i can only help you with the regex. Do take care of one thing, you might need to put start and end anchors i.e. `^` and `$` at start and end of your regex respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
^\+?\d{3}[ -]?\d{7}$
```

This will match:

- An optional `+` at the beginning
- Followed by exactly three digits
- Followed by a single optional space or `-`.
- Followed by exactly seven more digits

---

If, however "phone number total digits is not need to setup as 10 digits" means you do not want to restrict the number of digits (or specify exactly how many go where), you can change the regex to:

```
^\+?\d+[ -]?\d+$
```

This will match:

- An optional `+` at the beginning
- Followed by at least one digit
- Followed by a single optional space or `-`.
- Followed by at least one more digit

---

Furthermore if you want to accept spaces and hyphens anywhere, I would do something like:

```
^(\+|\+ )?\d+([ -]?\d+)*$
```

This will match:

- An optional `+` at the beginning (optionally followed by a space)
- At least one digit
- Zero or more groups of (a space or hyphen, followed by at least one digit)

Comment: fine. i was try to use ur code but unfortunately, Warning (512): Could not find validation handler was generated ?
did the model validate as this -> 'phone' => array(
    'rule' => array('^\+?\d+[ -]?\d+$'), is the right ways?

Comment: I believe it would be `'rule' => array('custom', '^...$')`. Otherwise it will look for a rule *named* "^\+?\d+[ -]?\d+$"

Comment: that don't wrong too. 
when i put a notempty array into it . as phone' => array( 'notempty' => array( 'rule' => array('custom','^.....$'), ), ), 
and warning show : Warning (2): preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: You might be running into backslash hell? Try doubling each backslash (one to escape the backslash itself, and one for the regex): `^(\\+|\\+ )?\\d+([ -]?\\d+)*$`

Comment: Also that syntax seems strange. Wouldn't you want something like `'phone' => array('notEmpty' => array('rule' => 'notEmpty'), 'mask' => array('rule' => array('custom', '^...$')))`? See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Comment: actually what's the 'mask' worked as? 
because now when i try to input value and send . it's show a validate message wrote as 'mask' whichs located bottom of the input field of phone.

Comment: Yeah it's an arbitrary name for the validation. Look at the link I gave you, and specifically at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#multiple-rules-per-field